# Skipping Login activity on second time app opening

Tags: android, authentication

I am working on an app where user is redirected to a navigation drawer activity depending on his login type. There are total 3 login types. Now, my problem is when i fetch login type from shared preference and try to redirect user to his drawer on second time app opening, it does not skip the login screen. I shows the preference data in toast as is, but does not skip the login activity.

Can any one help?

```
final SessionManagement session = new SessionManagement(getApplicationContext());




    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Login Status: " + session.isLoggedIn(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    session.checkLogin();
```

and this is my isLoggedin function

```
  public boolean isLoggedIn(){
    return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
}
```

this is checkLogin function

```
    public void checkLogin(){
    // Check login status
    if(!this.isLoggedIn()){
        // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, MembersArea.class);
        // Closing all the Activities
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // Staring Login Activity
        _context.startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

this all sits in SessionManagement class

I also have this function redirectAuto

```
  public void redirectAuto(String userType){
    // Check login status
    if(this.isLoggedIn()){

        if(userType == "type1"){
            Intent intent = new Intent(_context, Type1.class);
            _context.startActivity(intent);
        }else if(userType == "type2"){
            Intent intent = new Intent(_context, Type2.class);
            _context.startActivity(intent);
        }else if(userType == "type3"){
            Intent intent = new Intent(_context, Type3.class);

            _context.startActivity(intent);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(_context, "Please login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

}
```

but when i call this if isLoggedIn is false, it does not go any where... Just stays at Login screen

Comment: @codeMagic added my code. Please see

Comment: The first thing I see is you are comparing Strings wrong. You should be using `.equals()`

Comment: Is the pref returning that you are logged in or no? If it is then your problem is probably the comparing of Strings. If it is false then you probably need to show how you are setting that pref.

Comment: @codeMagic Yes. It isLoggedIn is returning true when user is logged in, I am changing == by `.equals()`

Comment: AND ITS WORKING! you were right @codeMagic. I was comparing it wrong. `equals()` did it! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it's working! :)